How to move a shaft with a precision of ~10nm
The goal is to move an equipment with a few nanometers precision (for a hobby). I don't require an exact measure of what the current distance is, but "just" be able to increase/decrease it by a few nm at a time.
The end goal is to shift the "payload" anywhere with a period of ~500nm and at some fixed offset of ~150nm (e.g. 650nm, 1150nm, 1650, 2150nm, etc). So "accuracy" is not really required (I don't need to know if the system is at 650 or 1150 for example), but precision is a must - it would be good that I could place the system at in [1140 ; 1160]nm, for example.
In order to get this precision we could use piezo actuators (thanks for the suggestion from MTA in https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/97757/how-to-move-a-shaft-with-a-precision-of-10nm?noredirect=1#comment166378_97757).
I also thought about using a combination of gear trains and worm gear and make this (I don't know the name of this piece) slide:

But maybe this won't work (maybe too many "loose" parts which increase the error?) or there is a far better idea.
Also, I wouldn't mind (at all) some links were the parts could be purchased.
Thank you

What is the size and mass of the payload?

So what actuators did you find and what did you find about closed loop control? If you apply those you should get a suitable solution.

https://hackaday.com/2022/02/08/working-model-reveals-amazing-engineering-of-webbs-mirror-actuators/

differential screws would be the easiest to make. Or you could make use of flexures they can also rather easily do this if you have acess to say a wire edm or waterjet.

See: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PaypcVFPs48
